# Excel formula issue for entering "0" with empty cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a production report for my work and all of the tasks that are done are counted for each employee. I have my data, my pivot, and my main dash that points all my data to go where I want it to go. The problem is, when someone does not complete a task for the day I get an error message when all I need it to say is "0". I have done research and cannot find the exact formula to apply to my excel report that will formulate a "0" for empty cells instead of an error message. Please help? Thanks

Comment: What does your data look like? What are the existing by queries?

Comment: There is no queries, I am just trying to have a cell point to specific data in the pivot table but return a "0" if there is no information instead of a "refError". Does that help?

Comment: Without knowing the formula /pivot table setup you use it's impossible to tell how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried an iserror formula?

eg =IF(ISERROR(D3/0),0, D3/0)

The iserror returns a true value if the formula errors, in the above if d3/0 errors it returns a 0 value otherwise it calculates d3/0.

Answer (score 1):

A step one solution might be the replace all the empty cells in you data with a zero. This can easily be done by highlighting the area. Then use find a replace; leave replace blank and add 0 to replace with.   Not a great solution but it should help. You could then record a simple Marco to automate these steps.

I tried using Find and Select Special, then used blanks, but it won't let me replace all the values at once.